# Tag rename request: [crate] to [crate-training]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We have a tag for crating animals, [crate](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate), but it makes more sense to me that it would be called [crate-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate-training). Could we get [crate](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate) turned into [crate-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate-training)?

Comment: How do we even have crate-training if there are no questions in it? I thought tags w no questions disappeared?

Comment: @Zaralynda I think it's just because I used markup to format it as a tag. I don't think we actually have the tag.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking I used it in my question of levels of specificity (which means I had seen it), but I just said it could be used.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [crate-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate-training) over [crate](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate) for all crate related questions. [crate-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate-training) seems to me to include the selection of crates (design, sizing, etc) because that will affect training.  [crate](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate), to me, doesn't seem to include the behavior of the animal, and so it is a more restrictive tag.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is no, questions about crate behavior, design and crate sizing would not fit will in [crate-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate-training) but do fit in [crate](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate).  There are only 4 questions at the moment, not seeing a need for a more narrow/restrictive tag.