# Tag pluralization list

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

[Running this query on DataSE](http://data.stackexchange.com/pets/query/283214/tags-that-might-need-to-be-pluralized) I found some tags I think that would make more sense to be pluralized based on the other tags we have.

- [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) (Note: The similar tag [terrariums](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terrariums) is plural)
- [bearded-dragon](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bearded-dragon)
- [betta](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betta)
- [budgerigar](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budgerigar)
- [cage](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cage)
- [certificate](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificate)
- [cichlid](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cichlid)
- [cocker-spaniel](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cocker-spaniel)
- [community-aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-aquarium)
- [crate](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate) ([or crate-training](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1912/tag-rename-request-crate-to-crate-training))
- [crossbreed](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crossbreed)
- [danio](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danio)
- [disaster](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disaster)
- [gerbil](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gerbil)
- [habitat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habitat) ([or remove it](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/habitat-synonym-tag-or-eliminate))
- [herbivore](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/herbivore)
- [maine-coon](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maine-coon)
- [pig](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pig)
- [platy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platy) (Should probably be [platyfish technically](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Platy_(fish)))
- [pleco](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pleco) (Should also be the full name *plecostomus*, rather than the nickname)
- [pond](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pond)
- [rat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rat)
- [recall](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recall)
- [reef-tank](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reef-tank)
- [senior-pet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senior-pet)
- [skin-condition](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skin-condition)
- [sound](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound)
- [tetra](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetra)
- [thundershirt](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thundershirt) (Although there's only one question using this tag, so it might not even be needed.)
- [veterinarian](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veterinarian)
- [welsh-collie](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/welsh-collie)
- [whippet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whippet)

Comment: Related [Do ALL tags need to be made plural?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/392/do-all-tags-need-to-be-made-plural)

Comment: I am pro-consistency.

Comment: I support this. It strikes me as odd that some tags are plural and some aren't.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that these should be plural.  [rat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rat) in particular needs to be [rats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rats).

For the grammatically-impaired, here are my suggested changes based on the provided list:

- [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) **pluralize to** [aquariums](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquariums)
- [bearded-dragon](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bearded-dragon)  **pluralize to** [bearded-dragons](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bearded-dragons)
- [betta](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betta)  **pluralize to** [bettas](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bettas)
- [budgerigar](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budgerigar)  **pluralize to** [budgerigars](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budgerigars) **add common synonym** [budgies](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budgies)
- [cage](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cage) **pluralize to** [cages](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cages)
- [certificate](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificate) **rename to** [certifications](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certifications) **add synonym** [certificates](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificates)
- [cichlid](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cichlid) **pluralize to** [cichlids](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cichlids)
- [cocker-spaniel](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cocker-spaniel) **pluralize to** [cocker-spaniels](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cocker-spaniels)
- [community-aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-aquarium) **pluralize to** [community-aquariums](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-aquariums)
- [crate](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate) **rename to** [crate-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crate-training) **add synonym** [crates](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crates)
- [crossbreed](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crossbreed) **rename to** [crossbreeds](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crossbreeds) **add synonyms** [mongrels](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongrels) [mutts](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutts) [designer-pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/designer-pets) [mixes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixes) [hybrids](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hybrids)
- [danio](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danio) **rename to** [danios](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danios)
- [disaster](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disaster) **rename to** [disasters](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disasters)
- [gerbil](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gerbil) **rename to** [gerbils](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gerbils)
- [habitat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habitat) **has been removed**
- [herbivore](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/herbivore) **rename to** [herbivores](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/herbivores)
- [maine-coon](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maine-coon) **rename to** [maine-coons](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maine-coons)
- [pig](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pig) **rename to** [pigs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pigs) **add synonym** [hogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hogs)
- [platy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platy) **rename to** [platy-fish](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platy-fish) **add synonyms** [platys](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platys) [platies](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platies)
- [pleco](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pleco) **rename to** [plecostomus](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plecostomus)
- [pond](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pond) **rename to** [ponds](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ponds)
- [rat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rat) **rename to** [rats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rats)
- [recall](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recall) **rename to** [recalls](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recalls)
- [reef-tank](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reef-tank) **rename to** [reef-tanks](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reef-tanks)
- [senior-pet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senior-pet) **rename to** [senior-pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senior-pets)
- [skin-condition](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skin-condition) **rename to** [skin-conditions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skin-conditions)
- [sound](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) **rename to** [sounds](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sounds) **add synonym** [noises](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noises)
- [tetra](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetra) **rename to** [tetras](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetras)
- [thundershirt](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thundershirt)  **rename to** [thundershirts](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thundershirts)
- [veterinarian](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veterinarian) **rename to** [veterinarians](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veterinarians)
- [welsh-collie](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/welsh-collie) **rename to** [welsh-collies](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/welsh-collies)
- [whippet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whippet) **rename to** [whippets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whippets), whip it good.

All of this should have moderator intervention, otherwise many questions are going to get updated and flagged, and if I did it myself, then I'd be listed as the creator of those tags, which is not necessarily fair for badge purposes.

I'll volunteer to do it all for you if you give me temp permissions.

Comment: Can a moderator swap this stuff out, or do we need to do this manually?